# Does Windows 8 C# have support for SyndicationFeed?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, syndicationfeed

Browsing through
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230232.aspx
I could not find anywhere that said Windows 8 Apps support the use of SyndicationFeed. Is there a way to still use this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried looking in the [`Windows.Web.Syndication`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br244529.aspx) Classes. There is a [`SyndicationFeed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx) there

Comment: That I did not look into doing yet. I checked it and it appears to be there. Thank you!

Comment: I also found adding 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Libraries\Client\System.ServiceModel.Syndication.dll

adds it as well...